# VBScript to move specified files (e.g *.txt) from a folder (and subfolder) to a specified location

Tags: file, vbscript, directory

I have this script for accessing a root folder and all the subfolders of the root. The script is meant to find all the PDF files and copy them in a specified folder. Unfortunately something is not right since I get an error when trying to obtain the current folder and copy the files with `fso.CopyFile curDir & "\*.pdf", "C:\users"`.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objStartFolder = "C:\Users\jula\Desktop\docs"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
WScript.Echo objFolder.Path

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
WScript.Echo "Start, I think"

ShowSubfolders objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder In Folder.SubFolders
        'displaying the current folder it's searching in
        WScript.Echo Subfolder.Path

        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)

        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

        For Each objFile In colFiles
            'obtaining the curent directory name
            curDir = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
            objFSO.CopyFile curDir & "\*.pdf", "C:\users'\jula\Desktop\folderToMoveIn"
            WScript.Echo objFile.Name
        Next

        WScript.Echo

        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: And the error is ... *what?*

Comment: Being unable to copy the files from the current directory to the specified folder as I get an "unable to find path" error, I think it' because how I specify the source folder to copy from  curDir & "\8.pd"

Comment: Please *show* the exact error you're getting. Do not paraphrase.